# Adding href tag to image breaks carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm trying to make a slider that displays 4 horizontal images at a time and each image is hyperlinked.  Adding hyperlinks to it breaks the code.  I added "a" tags to the CSS and expected it to continue working, but it made the slides vertical and displayed all of them, instead of just 4 at a time. Could there be a problem with the js?  I've added the css portion below because I think that is the problem.  The full code is in the jsfiddle link below.  Essentially i'm trying to make something that appears similar to the netflix title preview carousel.

Here is my jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/Kronos11/s9uqjy6p/

```css
.container a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider a {
  --items-per-screen: 4;
  --slider-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 var(--img-gap);
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--slider-index) * -100%));
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.slider > a img {
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% / var(--items-per-screen));
  max-width: calc(100% / var(--items-per-screen));
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  padding: var(--img-gap);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the question is related to JavaScript instead of Java. Those are two different languages. Please edit your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your CSS, HTML & JS file: A class "new-class" is added as a container to all the images and separated from the button, you were targeting the wrong class to update the 'itemsPerScreen' and 'sliderIndex', hence, it's returning a "NaN" which is causing an error and you didn't call the `calculateProgressBar()` in the `onHandleClick()`. I hope this is helpful and it's not too late.
Codepen link: https://codepen.io/beth-codes/pen/BaEzJBw?editors=1111

```
 <div class="container">
  <button class="handle left-handle">
    <div class="text">&#8249;</div>
  </button>
   <div class="new-class">
       <div class="slider">
         <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-v8-jebvHtY">
           <img src="https://streamwon.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/Blue-and-Yello-intro.jpg">
         </a>
       </div>
     //other slider images container
  </div>
  <button class="handle right-handle">
    <div class="text">&#8250;</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .new-class{
   margin-block: 5rem;
   display: flex;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   --slider-index: 0;
   --items-per-screen: 4;
  }

.slider{
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--slider-index) * -150%));
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
 }
```

JS

```
      document.addEventListener("click", e => {
     const handle = e.target.matches(".handle") ? e.target : e.target.closest(".handle");
     if (handle) onHandleClick(handle);
  });

  const throttleProgressBar = throttle(() => {
     document.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar").forEach(calculateProgressBar);
  }, 250);

  function updateProgressBars() {
     document.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar").forEach(calculateProgressBar);
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", throttleProgressBar);

  function calculateProgressBar(progressBar) {
     progressBar.innerHTML = "";
     const slider = progressBar.closest(".row").querySelector(".new-class");
     if (!slider) return; // Handle missing slider
     const itemCount = slider.children.length;
     const itemsPerScreen = parseInt(getComputedStyle(slider).getPropertyValue("--items-per-screen"));
     let sliderIndex = parseInt(getComputedStyle(slider).getPropertyValue("--slider-index"));
     const progressBarItemCount = Math.ceil(itemCount / itemsPerScreen);
     if (sliderIndex >= progressBarItemCount) {
        slider.style.setProperty("--slider-index", progressBarItemCount - 1);
        sliderIndex = progressBarItemCount - 1;
     }

     for (let i = 0; i < progressBarItemCount; i++) {
        const barItem = document.createElement("div");
        barItem.classList.add("progress-item");
        if (i === sliderIndex) {
           barItem.classList.add("active");
        }
        progressBar.append(barItem);
     }
  }

  function onHandleClick(handle) {
     const progressBar = handle.closest(".row").querySelector(".progress-bar");
     const slider = handle.closest(".container").querySelector(".new-class");
     if (!progressBar || !slider) return; // Handle missing elements
     const sliderItemCount = slider.querySelectorAll(".slider").length;
     const progressBarItemCount = sliderItemCount;
     let sliderIndex = parseInt(getComputedStyle(slider).getPropertyValue("--slider-index"));

     slider.style.transform = `translateX(${sliderIndex * 0}%)`;

     if (handle.classList.contains("left-handle")) {
        if (sliderIndex - 1 < 0) {
           return; // Exit if already at the beginning
        } else {
           slider.style.setProperty("--slider-index", sliderIndex - 1);
           updateProgressBar(progressBar, sliderIndex, sliderIndex - 1);
        }
     }

     if (handle.classList.contains("right-handle")) {
        if (sliderIndex + 1 >= progressBarItemCount) {
           slider.style.setProperty("--slider-index", 0);
           updateProgressBar(progressBar, sliderIndex, 0);
        } else {
           slider.style.setProperty("--slider-index", sliderIndex + 1);
           updateProgressBar(progressBar, sliderIndex, sliderIndex + 1);
        }
     }
  }

  function updateProgressBar(progressBar, currentIndex, nextIndex) {
     if (!progressBar) return;
     const progressBarChildren = progressBar.children;
     progressBarChildren[currentIndex]?.classList.remove("active");
     progressBarChildren[nextIndex]?.classList.add("active");
     updateProgressBars();
  }

  function throttle(cb, delay = 1000) {
     let shouldWait = false;
     let waitingArgs;
     const timeoutFunc = () => {
        if (waitingArgs == null) {
           shouldWait = false;
        } else {
           cb(...waitingArgs);
           waitingArgs = null;
           setTimeout(timeoutFunc, delay);
        }
     };

     return (...args) => {
        if (shouldWait) {
           waitingArgs = args;
           return;
        }

        cb(...args);
        shouldWait = true;
        setTimeout(timeoutFunc, delay);
     };
  }
```